# How to disable the accept button in code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

In Microsoft Visual Basic 2010, a form has a property called AcceptButton. This can be set to the ok button of the form in the designer or by code, like this `Me.AcceptButton = Me.OKbutton`.

I would like to know how to disable this property in code, with something like `Me.AcceptButton = Null`, **note** this does not work. In the designer this property can be left set to (none).

The reason I would like to know how to achieve this is as follows. I have a textbox that the user enters data into; when they press enter an error check is done. This uses the following code

```
    Private Sub textbox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles textbox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Return Then
```

The problem I am having is that this code does not run if the AcceptButton property is enabled, due to the dual use of the return key. I would therefore like to temporarily disable then re-enable the AcceptButton property using code.

If I do not set the AcceptButton this code will run.

Comment: Why do you need to enable it in the first place?

Comment: Why tag a VB.Net question as VB6?

Comment: Why do you need to enable it in the first place?
I would like to use the accept button for the user to press enter and accept the values in this settings dialog. However before everythig is set the ok and accept buttons of this dialog are disabled, this means the enter key can not be used as the accept button. When this is the case I would like the enter key to be used to allow the user to press enter in the textbox and if it is a valid entry this enables the ok and accept buttons.

Comment: It also disables the ok and accept button if an invalid entry is made, so again I would then like to use the enter key to accept the changes in the textbox.

Comment: Why tag a VB.Net question as VB6?
Sorry wrong tag, changed it now.

Comment: @josh you changed tags wrongly. It is [tag:vb.net], not [tag:vb6] question.

Comment: Im confused is Microsoft visual basic 2010 Express, vb.net or vb6

Comment: VB Express is VB.Net.

Comment: @josh All versions of VB released in the last 15 years have been VB.Net. VB6 is explicitly Visual Basic 6. I have now corrected the tag for you and there is no need to change it back again.

Answer (score 2):

Don't tinker with the AcceptButton property, it gives important feedback to the user.  Fix the **real** problem, set the TextBox' AcceptsReturn property to True.

Comment: The textbox's AcceptsReturn property was already set to true.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to disable accept button use as Me.AcceptButton = Nothing

Answer (score 0):

Leave the AcceptButton() property **not** set.  Then, in your KeyDown() handler, if enter is pressed and everything passes your tests:

```
OKbutton.PerformClick()
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it will only preform the OKbutton.PreformClick in the keyDown event, which is a handler of the textbox. I would like the enter key to accept the changes to the form if the textbox is never entered.

Comment: Is there anything else on the form that can receive focus?

Comment: Yes there is a few things. There is another textbox, a NumericalUpDown, 2 radio buttons and a normal button(which is not the ok, cancle and accept button). But I have got around this problem now by temporarly disabling the accept button using Me.AcceptButton = Nothing and then reenabling it after the check is performed with Me.AcceptButton = Me.OKbutton.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to **disable** your button and then only re-enable it when your conditions are met.  Then you don't have to trap Enter in the TextBox handler.  Here's a simply example:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.AcceptButton = Me.OKbutton
        Me.OKbutton.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        ValidateEntries()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ValidateEntries()
        ' ... put your logic in here to determine if all the fields in the form are in a valid state ...
        ' set the Enabled state of OKbutton accordingly:

        Dim valid As Boolean = True ' assume valid until proven otherwise

        ' Made up validation code:
        Dim value As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, value) Then
            If value < 60 Then
                valid = False
            End If
        Else
            valid = False
        End If

        Me.OKbutton.Enabled = valid
    End Sub

    Private Sub OKbutton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles OKbutton.Click
        MessageBox.Show("OK")
    End Sub

End Class
```